# Spice_ Capacitors in series

Tags: simulation, spice

I try to simulate an RLC circuit depicted in the annexed file. I have noticed that ngspice is not able to compile two capacitors which are connected in series. The netlist is written as follows:

```
    * The global plasma model
    VRF 0 1 SIN(0 100 0.275732
    CBC 2 1 5.25154
    Cs 3 2 0.1407107F
    RB 4 3 5.25154
    LB 5 4 212.692
    VG 0 5 dc 10
    .END
```

This circuit can't be solved transient. I get the following error or warning message :

```
Warning: vrf: no DC value, transient time 0 value used 
Warning:singular  matrix: check nodes 2 and 2
```

I would be very grateful, if somebody can give me a Hint on what went wrong. best regard 
Nina

Answer (score 2):

Try putting large resistors (10M, say) in parallel with the capacitors, to give a DC path.

Answer (score 1):

The circuit has no unique DC solution. Node `2` could have any value and will never settle to a value independent of the past history of the circuit.

Some SPICEs add a 1 GOhm resistor to ground from every node to avoid this problem, but it appears your SPICE does not (or maybe there is a check-box where you asked it not do this).

You could either explicitly add a high-value resistor to ground from node `2`, or, as suggested in another answer, add a high value resistor in parallel with each capacitor.